# Microsoft graph-api endpoint to view admin center global tenant settings

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is it possible to get global tenant settings via a graph api endpoint?  For example, if I want to programmatically determine if my tenant's sharepoint settings limit external sharing by domain, is there a graph api endpoint for this?  Based on my research I have yet to find an endpoint that gives me access in either v1 or beta (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getonedriveactivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0)

It does seem possible to gather this information via powershell using the SharePoint Online module by doing

```
Get-SPOTenant | fl SharingDomainRestrictionMode,SharingAllowedDomainList
```

For added context here is the same setting in the sharepoint admin center:
[image]

If admin center endpoints (SharePoint, OneDrive, Azure AD, etc.) are not currently available in the graph api are they on the future roadmap?

Thank you in advance for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not supported and its not under road map. 
Please raise [user voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).